# How to move a curve that has an array without distortion

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have an array tied to a curve (and I've also added an empty axis to get a slight twist.) How do I move the entire array of objects without deforming the array? I tried moving the axis as well as the curve both individually and together.

[image: The original array and curve]

[image: Deforms when I try to move it]

Comment: Do you want each individual object of the array to not be deformed or do you want the general curve to retain its form ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! You have to press tab on the curve to go into edit mode, select all the points, then move it where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the curve,array and empty together  by using shift +click to select multiple or simply use box select to select all of them  and then move them wherever you want. I will surely work fine .